# does an inside the cabinet outlet need gfci?

Tags: gfci

I have an outlet inside a base cabinet that powers the downdraft for the cooktop.
It trips the gfci on the counter from which it is fed.
Can I feed this cabinet outlet which only serves the downdraft without gfci protection?

Answer (score 1):

There are some rare kitchen GFCI exceptions - e.g., refrigerator, but only when it is a single receptacle (not the usual duplex), but I doubt the downdraft would get an exemption because there is no real basis for that - as opposed to a refrigerator where there is a real risk of serious harm (both monetary and health) due to spoilage.

But more importantly, if it is tripping the GFCI then you very likely **have an actual Ground Fault**. Fix the problem, don't bypass it. I would be particularly concerned with a downdraft because things happen fast when cooking - spills & thrills & wet hands & steam - not a good place to have an actual ground fault within easy reach.

Comment: Actually, the range hood receptacle does *not* need to be GFCI since it doesn't serve a countertop surface.  You're right that fixing the ground fault is the correct solution to this problem, though.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm not so sure about that. The question was not about a "range hood" (which I agree should be like lighting and exempt from GFCI) but rather about **downdraft**. As I understand it (and I just Google'd some pictures to make sure I remembered correctly), a downdraft fan is typically a popup device next to the cooktop, and therefore is in range of hands while cooking...so even if it may technically be exempt (though maybe it is not exempt, I really don't know for sure), to me it would be logical to protect it.